# Chart Plot Points - Show tool tip in OxyPlot

Tags: wpf, xaml, oxyplot

I am working on a WPF app that requires charting. I am using [OxyPlot](http://oxyplot.org/). My chart is rendering properly using the following XAML.

```
<oxy:Plot Height="800" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
  <oxy:Plot.Series>
    <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Series1Points}" MarkerType="Diamond" Title="Series 1" />
    <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Series2Points}" MarkerType="Diamond" Title="Series 2" />
  </oxy:Plot.Series>
</oxy:Plot>
```

I have one challenge that I have been unsuccessful in figuring out. When a series renders, each data point is shown as a diamond. When a user puts their mouse on the diamond, I would like to show a tooltip with the X and Y values of the data point. How can you do that? It seems like it should be possible. Yet, I'm not having any success.

Comment: Not sure that understood you correctly. Repeated your example - the tooltip is displayed so: http://i.stack.imgur.com/utdOS.png  Or you want to change the standard tooltip?

Comment: I see. I noticed you have to click to get the tooltip to appear. Is there a way to make the tooltip appear on hover?

Comment: Maybe this helps you, I was using oxyplot, and the decided to start my own library because I found I needed more, https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tooltip is showed just left clicking. To show it when hover you need to modify oxyplot controller:

**c#:**

```
public PlotController customController { get; private set; }

...

//Sets the controller to enable show tracker on mouse hover
customController = new PlotController();
customController.UnbindMouseDown(OxyMouseButton.Left);
customController.BindMouseEnter(PlotCommands.HoverSnapTrack);
```

**xaml:**

```
<oxy:Plot Controller="{Binding customController}" Height="800" ... >
```